# unite python "for" with tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, tkinter

I have a simple problem. I have a list (l1) of values and I want that for every value in list it makes Button, which add value to textvariable (tkvar). Program make buttons, but each of them add **last value** of list. How can I make that button will add right value to "tkvar" based on his position?

```
import Tkinter as Tk
main=Tk.Tk()
l1=["A", "B", "C"]
def phase(): 
    for i in l1:
        Tk.Button(main, text = i, command=lambda: read(i)).pack(side="left")
    e=Tk.Entry(main, textvariable=tkvar)
    e.pack()
    return
def read(q,*par):
    tkvar.set(q)
tkvar=Tk.StringVar()
phase()
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in l1:
    Tk.Button(main, text = i, command=lambda: read(i)).pack(side="left")
```

You've run a loop within which you create closures using `lambda`. Each of those calls `read(i)` when called, and the `i` comes from the scope of `phase`, long after the for loop is finished.

One workaround is to get the value of `i` and store it within the lambda as a default argument:

```
lambda i=i: read(i)
```

This stores the value that `i` had when the lambda was created within the function's default arguments. We can check the different behaviour of the functions:

```
>>> i=123
>>> lambda i=i: read(i)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f8d714b8a28>
>>> dis.dis(_)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (read)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> lambda: read(i)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f8d714b8aa0>
>>> dis.dis(_)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (read)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (i)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

It might be cleaner to do a partial application, replacing the lambda entirely:

```
from functools import partial
command = partial(read, i)
```

In that case, both `read` and `i` are looked up to make the `partial` call, and there will be no global loads, thus not keeping the local variables of `phase` alive.